# Работа с динамическим массивом

Tags: c++, память, visual-studio-2017

Нужно создать массив, который состоит из положительных значений на главной диагонали двухмерной матрицы.

Использую динамический массив, но у меня что-то не получается, выводит одно число - `-84663632` - для всех элементов.

Вот код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
        srand(time(NULL));
        int igor[5][5];
        int* ptrIgor = new int[6];
        cout << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                igor[i][j] = rand() % 41 - 20;
                cout << setw(5) << igor[i][j];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                if (i == j)
                {
                    igor[i][j] = ptrIgor[i];
                }
            }
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++)
        {
            cout << setw(5) << ptrIgor[k];
        }
        delete[] ptrIgor;
        cout << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: А ничего, что вы в ptrIgor и не пишете? И, закономерно, получаете мусор, потому что выводите неинициализированные переменные

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала - может, здесь

```
igor[i][j] = ptrIgor[i];
```

нужно поменять операнды местами? Вы же хотите хранить данные в `ptrIgor`, а не мусорить в `igor`?

Затем, у вас матрица 5x5, но вы, судя по

```
    for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++)
    {
        cout << setw(5) << ptrIgor[k];
    }
```

считаете, что будет *шесть* положительных элементов на диагонали?

Впрочем, вы в `ptrIgor` записываете почему-то **все** диагональные значения, а не только положительные. Да и как-то вы это странно делаете - не проще ли

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    if (igor[i][i] > 0)  ptrIgor[count++] = igor[i][i];
```

где `count` - счетчик. Вот [окончательное решение](https://ideone.com/GhYjp7):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    srand(time(nullptr));

    int igor[5][5];
    int* ptrIgor = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            igor[i][j] = rand() % 41 - 20;
            cout << setw(5) << igor[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        if (igor[i][i] > 0)
        {
            ptrIgor[count++] = igor[i][i];
        }

    for (int k = 0; k < count; k++)
    {
        cout << setw(5) << ptrIgor[k];
    }
    cout << endl;

    delete[] ptrIgor;
}
```

Comment: Я хочу понять как работать с динамическим массивом. Я ,допустим ,не знаю величину массива,который должен получить. Выделяю в памяти 6 ячеек. А если в диагонали матрицы 2 положительных элемента-я их записываю в массив и хочу вывести только эти 2 элемента как весь массив. Как мне избавиться от лишних ячеек,т .е. мусора?

Comment: Считайте, сколько их вы записали, и выводите ровно столько. Переменная-счетчик, равная изначально нулю; потом при каждом присваивании - увеличивайте на 1. А в последнем цикле не `k<6`, а `k<` этой переменной. "Избавляться* - т.е. выделять новый массив нужного размера, копировать и удалять старый - смысла не вижу.

Comment: так,положительные элементы оно-то выводит,но и мусор тоже ,там где не должноэлементов быть вообще


int q = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    if (igor[i][i] > 0)
    ptrIgor[i] = igor[i][i];
    q++;
  }
  cout << endl;
  for (int k = 0; k < q; k++)
  {
   cout << setw(5) << ptrIgor[k];
  }
  delete[] ptrIgor;
  cout << endl;
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}

Comment: Извините, я наврал немного. См. обновленный ответ.

Comment: все верно, премного благодарен

Comment: ,еще один вопрос.Обязательно ли нам здесь нужно было создавать динамический массив? И в каких случаях это нужно делать обязательно ?

Comment: :) Когда этого требует преподаватель :) Общего рецепта, я бы сказал, нет, в вашем случае он в общем-то не нужен. Обычно - когда размер слишком большой, чтобы размещать его в стеке. Более того, всякие динамические массивы в С++ реализуют с помощью тех же векторов - проще и надежнее, и не нужно помнить об удалении.